# Set HighStocks x-axis data dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying, if possible, to set HighStocks x-axis data coming from PHP. I googled, looked on highcharts documentation, and looked on here for an answer, but I can't seem to find one.
I'm using CodeIgniter as a PHP Framework, and I have no problem getting the data from the model, and then the controller passes the data to the view. I used HighCharts before, and setting the x-axis for HighChart is really easy.

```
xAxis: {
     categories: [<?= $high_charts_category_data ?>]

}
```

How can I do the same thing using HighStocks? 
As far as I know, the x-axis can only be a datetime value, and the $high_charts_category_data is an array of datetime with a format of "2014-10-31 11:45:41"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to have something other than `datetime` for the x-axis in Highstock (for example: categories)?

Comment: What your <?= $high_charts_category_data ?> print?

Comment: <?= $high_charts_category_data ?> is an array where each element is in the format of "2014-10-31 11:45:41", "2014-10-31 12:45:41", and so on. No, I'm not asking to change something other than datetime. I want to use <?= $high_charts_category_data ?> for HighStock x-axis data, which is a datetime format.

Comment: If you have your data as date-string, why not convert them to timestamps and pass it into the data of the series?

Comment: My series data(graph) is in percentages and the x-axis should be a timestamp. The purpose of the graph is to hover over the series(dots), and it tells the client that on this day(2013-10-31 11:10 AM), the job is/was at a certain percentage(20%). This is easily done using the Highchart but not in Highstock. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I'm a little unsure. I'm still hearing that "x-axis should be a timestamp", right? And the y-axis is the percentage? No? Please @-me to notify of responses.

Comment: @Ondkloss Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the process of this site, and I didn't see your comment. Anyways, you are correct that my x-axis is a timestamp. However, I cannot figure a way to set my dynamic data to the x-axis.

Comment: When using `datetime` the x-axis usually just shows from the values that are relevant to the points in your series. If you series goes from 2011 to 2014, that is what the x-axis shows. If you want it to be more specific you can use `min` and `max`, or if you want different labels they can be manipulated as well. You will have to create a example code of what you've tried, and I feel like a example image of what you want as a result could also help a lot here.

Comment: @Ondkloss Thanks! After reading your comment, I just realized I was doing it all wrong in the first place. It all make sense now! How do I give you an upvote?